# R: Adding quality control flags to data

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, case-when

I have a data frame containing sensor data which needs to be quality controlled. I need to be able to keep track of what changes have been made to the data so an additional column has been added to the data frame to contain comments. I wish to i) replace the -7999 values with NA values, and ii) add a column named 'QC_flag' which contains a comment if a -7999 value was changed to NA.

Is there a way to do it in a single line rather than having to call mutate twice? i.e. as part of the na_if argument or something similar.

```
require(tidyverse) 

dat <- tibble(sensor_a = c(5, 3, 5, 4, 5, -7999, 3, 5, 4, 4),
              sensor_b = c(300, 290, 370, 400, -7999, 200, 350, 480, 120, 280),
              sensor_c = c(-7999, -7999, -7999, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1700, 1600, 1200))

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(QC_flag = case_when(sensor_a == -7999 ~ '7999 error [Sensor A]',
                           sensor_b == -7999 ~ '7999 error [Sensor B]',
                           sensor_c == -7999 ~ '7999 error [Sensor C]')) %>% 
  mutate(sensor_a = na_if(sensor_a, -7999), 
         sensor_b = na_if(sensor_b, -7999), 
         sensor_c = na_if(sensor_c, -7999))
```

The initial data frame looks like this:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   sensor_a sensor_b sensor_c
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        5      300    -7999
 2        3      290    -7999
 3        5      370    -7999
 4        4      400     1500
 5        5    -7999     1600
 6    -7999      200     1700
 7        3      350     1800
 8        5      480     1700
 9        4      120     1600
10        4      280     1200
```

and the result then looks like this:

```
> dat2
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   sensor_a sensor_b sensor_c QC_flag              
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                
 1        5      300       NA 7999 error [Sensor C]
 2        3      290       NA 7999 error [Sensor C]
 3        5      370       NA 7999 error [Sensor C]
 4        4      400     1500 NA                   
 5        5       NA     1600 7999 error [Sensor B]
 6       NA      200     1700 7999 error [Sensor A]
 7        3      350     1800 NA                   
 8        5      480     1700 NA                   
 9        4      120     1600 NA                   
10        4      280     1200 NA
```

Comment: For the 2nd portion, i.e. replacing `-7999` with `NA`, you can try `mutate_at(vars(matches("sensor_[abc]")), ~(na_if(., -7999)))`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to have data in long format :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  #Create a row index
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  #Get data in long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  #Add QC_flag name if value is -7999 or else keep NA
  mutate(QC_flag = ifelse(value == -7999, paste0('7999 error [', name, ']'),NA), 
         #Replace -7999 with NA
         value = na_if(value, -7999)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  #Fill NA values in QC_flag
  fill(QC_flag, .direction = "updown") %>%
  #Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #Select relevant columns in order.
  select(starts_with('sensor'), QC_flag)

#       sensor_a sensor_b sensor_c QC_flag              
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                
# 1        5      300       NA 7999 error [sensor_c]
# 2        3      290       NA 7999 error [sensor_c]
# 3        5      370       NA 7999 error [sensor_c]
# 4        4      400     1500 NA                   
# 5        5       NA     1600 7999 error [sensor_b]
# 6       NA      200     1700 7999 error [sensor_a]
# 7        3      350     1800 NA                   
# 8        5      480     1700 NA                   
# 9        4      120     1600 NA                   
#10        4      280     1200 NA
```